# Is it possible to generate form fields in a webapp from a list of generic objects?

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts2

Here's the situation:
We want to have a Search page that takes in an ordered list of Attribute objects, and based on their 'type' (text input, dropdown, checkbox) generates and displays it in the appropriate manner. We'd also need to process the values for these fields in order to filter results. I'm at a loss for how we can accomplish this, any ideas/solutions? 
This is for a java webapp backed by struts2.

Comment: While this is possible, in my experience it's almost always a bad idea.  From a user experience perspective it's usually not a good idea to have totally dynamic GUIs in the way you describe.  And if the screens you're developing are relatively static, you're usually best off just hard coding the layout pieces.  I've been down this road before and ultimately decided to revert back to static layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. I'm not familiar with struts, but I guess it can't be that hard. Some pseudo-java-code to get you started:

```
private void init() {
    for(Attribute a : attributes) {
        SomeWebComponent c = createComponent(a);
        components.put(a, c);
    }
    renderComponents(components.values());
}

private SomeWebComponent createComponent(Attribute a) {
    if(a.getType().equals("text") return createTextInput();
    else if(a.getType().equals("list") return createListInput(a.getItems());
    ...
}

private void performSearch() {
    for(Attribute a : attributes) {
        SomeWebComponent c = components.get(a);;
        searchValues.put(a, c.getValue());
    }
    doSearch(searchValues);
}
```